# Search for specific name header column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How can I Search for specific name header column "DATA/HORA" and adapt to macro below?

```
Sub Data()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
 If InStr(cell.Value, "-") <> 0 Then
    cell.Value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
    "(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})", "$3/$2/$1")
End If

 cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
Next

End Sub

Function RegexReplace
------    
End Function
```

Comment: Use `.Find`. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: @Cris, I was just posting an answer to your other question when you deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
```

With:

```
Dim ColLetr As String
For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    If Cells(1, i) = "DATA/HORA" Then
        ColLetr = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
    End If
Next
lastRow = Range(ColLetr & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range(ColLetr & "1:" & ColLetr & lastRow)
```

**EDIT#1**:

To address the Comments:

```
Dim ColLetr As String
For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    If Cells(1, i) = "DATA/HORA" Then
        ColLetr = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If ColLetr = "" Then
    MsgBox "DATA/HORA not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
lastRow = Range(ColLetr & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range(ColLetr & "1:" & ColLetr & lastRow)
```

Comment: Missing an `Exit For`? Also what if there is no header with that match? `ColLetr` will be `""`

Comment: Both good comments.......an Exit For may improve speed a little.....if the match is not found then an error message and an Exit Sub......but that is a decision for the coder to make.